# Powershell Scheduled Task "Delay task for" option

Tags: powershell

I need to create Task Schedule with "Delay task for" option for 1 min. I can see PowerShell cmdlet New-ScheduledTaskTrigger has an option -RandomDelay, but I don't think it's valid. I can't see another option in Documentation either (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816(v=wps.630).aspx).

```
$DELAY = new-timespan -minutes 1
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon -RandomDelay $DELAY
```

Comment: It is valid, why do you think it isn't ? I am personally using it in a script and it works fine: https://github.com/majkinetor/posh/blob/master/MM_Admin/Register-LoginTask.ps1

Comment: Just run your script and it didn't work. [http://i.imgur.com/v3ZPXOy.png](http://i.imgur.com/v3ZPXOy.png)

Comment: Mhm... it works for me, every day. Can you give the command you used ?

Comment: Register-LoginTask "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe" -Delay "00:00:30"

Comment: What OS ? That works on 8.1+. Did you use admin console ?

Comment: Windows 10, running as administrator.

Comment: Mhm... I can't really tell then. Its strange. Try to use `schtasks.exe ... /DELAY ` instead, it will certainly work. Posh ST cmdlets are too verbose for my taste anyway.

Comment: Yes, schtasks works, but it lacks many options, that's why I want to use powershell

Comment: You could export the task to XML then import it using schtasks. That would bring all options.

Comment: -RandomDelay means the command will run at any random time from the task scheduled time until the RandomDelay time. This is not a guarantee that the command will run 1 minute after the scheduled time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add this part:

```
$T.Delay = 'PT1M'
```

Comment: Probably worth including the original code along with your answer, in a code block,  to make it clearer

Comment: I can't find what stands for the Delay property format, but I think it's similar to ISO 8601 duration format and its only valid designators are day designator and below https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Comment: New-ScheduledTaskTrigger : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Delay'.

Comment: does not work for windows server 2012 R2. Property `Delay` is not found.

Answer (score 1):

```
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$T.Delay = 'PT1M'
```

Nikolas answer is correct, just writing all code needed for clearity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command difference between PowerShell version 4 and later versions where the RandomDelay parameter is still accepted but then ignored.

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup

# 1 minute wait for windows to load critical services/profiles

if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 4) {  
    $trigger.RandomDelay = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1  
} else {  
    $trigger.Delay = "PT1M"  
}
```

It's real fun rebooting computers trying to find why some schedule tasks for users were failing with the following error because their profiles never got the script allocated time to load.

> "Task Scheduler failed to start "*" task for user "(NONE)". Additional
> Data: Error Value: 2147942487."

Comment: It's not ignored, it's literally random. There's no guarantee it will wait 1 minute, it can start anywhere between right away and 1 minute in this case.