# How can I create a Task Scheduler task with a built-in delay from startup in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-task-scheduler

I create a Task Scheduler Job using PowerShell. Using GUI there is a "advanced settings" with an option "delay task for:". I need it for a Scheduler "at startup". Using PowerShell there is the parameter "RandomDelay", but it's not the same?
My code:

```
$triggers = @()
$triggers += New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartUp -RandomDelay "00:00:30"
$triggers += New-SchedulerTaskTrigger -Daily -At "00:00" -RandomDelay "00:00:30"
```

RandomDelay for 30 sec. will be created for the daily scheduler, but not for the "startup".

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50759453/9898643) what you need?

Comment: no, it creates "delay" for a job with the scheduler "at:", not  for a job "atStartUp".